# How to enabling big_writes option during mounting of ntfs drives in kubuntu 22.10

Tags: file-copy, ntfs, kubuntu, ntfs-3g

During copying of big files i am suffering from high cpu usage. I read multiple linux forums saying adding big_writes flag during mount of ntfs drives results is less cpu usage.
Below is my mount_options.conf file content from /etc/udisk2/

```
[defaults]
defaults=noexec,nodev,nosuid,noatime
allow=exec,noexec,nodev,nosuid,atime,noatime,nodiratime,ro,rw,sync,dirsync,noload

vfat_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,flush,utf8,shortname,umask,dmask,fmask,codepage,iocharset,usefree,showexec
ntfs_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,windows_names,big_writes
ntfs_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,umask,dmask,fmask,locale,norecover,ignore_case,windows_names,compression,nocompression,big_writes
```

After rebooting the system too i feel no change to cpu usage during large file copying.
I am mounting the drives directly from dolphin and not using any terminal commands for doing the same.
What am i doing wrong ?
How do i check if big_writes flag is even enabled ?
My Linux Kernel version is 5.19.
DE: plasma 5.26.5
OS: Kubuntu 22.10
CPU: Ryzen 5600H

Answer (score 0):

You can add `big_writes` in the `/etc/fstab`, for example:

`UUID=21B9-8B8E /mnt/test auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,big_writes 0 0`

Then remount. To check if big_writes is enabled, do `ps ax | grep ntfs`.